# Can a .gitignore file in a subdirectory of a repo ignore items further up the directory tree?

Tags: git, repository

I have a respository that contains 2 different apps. I used to manage them both at the same time, so having to ignore one or the other was never a problem, but now i have to give one of the subsites to another person, and we are both are going to be working on the same repository at the same time.

Both apps are made with Angular, so they both already have a .gitignore ready for the node_modules folder.

Here are the paths for both .gitignore files:

> Code\Ventas\APP\Code\Client
>
> Code\Productor\APP\Code\Client

What i want to ask is: Is it possible to modify the .gitignore from the "Ventas" path in order to ignore everything from the "Productor" path? In that way me and the other person could treat both subsites as if they were hosted in different repositories, so 2 people can work on the same repository.

Answer (score 1):

No, a `.gitignore` file can only ignore files in the same directory or below it.

Even if it could, it wouldn't work as you imagine it, because as each of you work on your two separate apps, you will be making commits to the same repo. Each of you would would have to pull and merged the commits of the other unless you are working on separate branches (see below). I'm not sure if the merges would even work right with such a `.gitignore`

Below are three alternative solutions for you, from easiest to hardest. Easiest does not mean best.

#### use your IDE's ability to ignore directories

If you are using an IDE, you can configure your IDE project to ignore the other directory. It will still exist in your git worktree, but it will be invisible in the IDE.

You still have to be careful not to make and commit changes to the other directory, but it should be easy to avoid. You will still have to deal with pulling and merging the other persons commits, though those merges should be trivial.

#### make separate branches in the repo for each app

1. Create two new branches: `Ventas` and `Productor`. Keep the current main branch if the two apps have shared code.
2. In each of the branches delete the unwanted directory.
3. You can now work independently.
4. BUT it's not so pretty if you make changes to the shared code. You will have to patch the shared main branch with your changes to the shared code. There are many ways to do that, but it ain't trivial.

So the right way to do this is...

#### break up the repo

The fact that you want to .gitignore a whole directory branch of the repo indicates that you should split the repo. If there is shared code, you would split the repo into three repos and each of you would use git-submodule or git-subtree to incorporate the shared repo into your individual app repos.